# how to check a mutable string contains a string value or not in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have beeen storing some string values to an mutablearray to store in to a nsuserdefaults.like the way `

```
NSMutableArray *arrayObj = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"emoved"]];


    for(int i = 0 ; i<[searcharray count]; i++) 
    {
         NSLog(@"%@",searcharray); 
        NSDictionary *dictionarydate = [searcharray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *memeid=[[dictionarydate objectForKey:@"ID"]description];


        if([dictionarydate objectForKey:@"dateOfInfo"])
        {
            if ([arrayObj containsObject:memeid])
            {              

            }
            else
            {
                [arrayObj addObject:memeid];
            }
        }




    }
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arrayObj forKey:@"emoved"];
```

` so when printng you need to add a value only at once .but when i am priting that value i am seing the same value is added to the array multiple times.is there anything wrong in my approach can anybody point out?

Comment: Can you display log info about arrayObj and searcharray

Comment: remove description from here, waste.....        NSString *memeid=[[dictionarydate objectForKey:@"ID"]description];

Comment: arrayobj supposed to be consist of like 291,292like that.but it is showing as 291,293,293,293like that.that is not to be happen.serchfriendarray is an arry of dictionaries.

Comment: Do you want searching logic or what you are trying for ?

Answer (score 0):

You should allocate and initialize your NSMutableArray like

```
NSMutableArray *arrayObj = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"emoved"]];
```

If you aren't using ARC, don't forget to release your arrayObj right after you're done with it

Comment: then also it has nothing to do repeating of the elements is it?

Comment: can i do this so many times because so many allocation ?do it in so many occasions..as in so many loops.

Comment: Well it depends, if you're using ARC it will handle memory managment for you, the optimization of your code is up to you. Where are you calling this method and how many times you need to update your data?

Comment: Well that might happen when you haven't set your array to NSUserDefaults. your algorithm should -> a) check if [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"emoved"] is not nil.if it is, you should create new array and fill it with all the data objects you want in NSUserDefaults. b)if it's not nil, you can use your algorithm posted above

Comment: i am trying to store an nsmutable array to nsuserdefaults,so that i need to edit it.